# What is time_zone variable in mysql, and why should I change it

Tags: mysql, timezone, mariadb

I am watching a tutorial about mysql, and left me asking myself about what the variable `time_zone` does and why it needs to be changed.

Currently, I have the following value for for `time_zone` and `NOW()` function.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%time_zone%';
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| system_time_zone | CET    |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM |
+------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2017-03-10 22:38:49 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, the tutorial suggests, that `| time_zone | SYSTEM |` shouldn't be used, and instead I should download [Time zone description tables](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html) (also, yes I'm on windows)

What I don't understand is, what (in laymans terms) could happen if I don't use mysql as is. Also, `NOW()` prints out the current time in my city/country ... so it seems like it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be used for timezone conversions such as CONVERT_TZ()
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

If you don't use date functions or timestamps it won't matter much to you.

It's suggested to store everything in UTC and then display in the local time zone.
So in that case it would be useful.

Also, if you are considering day light savings its really clutch as it does the offset for you depending on the time of year and timezone set

Comment: thank for the simple answer. I didn't understand the last sentences though :)

Answer (score 1):

When you store a date&time into `DATETIME`, it is like taking a picture of a clock.

When you store into a `TIMESTAMP`, the local time is converted according to the timezone to UTC.  That value is stored in the database.  When you fetch it back out; it is reconverted.  If you are in the same timezone in both cases, you cannot see any difference.  That is, at *appears* to operate just like `DATETIME`.  However, if someone on the other side of the world fetched that same column, they see it converted to *their* timezone.

The TZ description tables need to be installed separately.  This is (I assume) because they keep changing.

"Why should I change it"?  Normally you should set it to `SYSTEM` and have your computer set appropriately.  Then forget it.  If you move to a different timezone, *then* change the system setting.

Otherwise, it sounds like the tutorial is wasting your time.